# My graphQL query in my reacts app is returning null for all fields

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I have a node app which takes a graphQL query from a react.js frontend and returns data from a mongoDB collection. I have a query which returns all the documents in a collection and that works fine. However, I have another query which takes a string value and returns only the matching document. This doesn't work and returns null every time.

I've added all the relevant code below if anyone can spot what I'm doing wrong. I've been looking at this all day and can't figure out why it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated,

cheers...

This is my schema:

```
    const graphql = require('graphql');
    const Service = require('../models/service');

    const {
      GraphQLObjectType,
      GraphQLID,
      GraphQLList,
      GraphQLSchema,
      GraphQLString,
    } = graphql;

    const ServiceType = new GraphQLObjectType({
      name: 'Service',
      fields: () => ({
        page: { type: GraphQLString },
        title: { type: GraphQLString },
        tagline: { type: GraphQLString },
      }),
    });

    const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
      name: 'RootQueryType',
      fields: {
        service: {
          type: ServiceType,
          args: { page: { type: GraphQLString } },
          resolve(parent, args) {
            return Service.find({ page: args.page });
          },
        },
        services: {
          type: new GraphQLList(ServiceType),
          resolve(parent, args) {
            return Service.find({});
          },
        },
      },
    });

    module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({ query: RootQuery });
```

This is the GQL that doesn't work:

```
    const GET_SERVICE = gql`
      query ($page: String!) {
        service(page: $page) {
          title
          body
        }
      }
    `;
```

This is how I use the query above:

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_SERVICE, {
        variables: { page: "myservice" },
    });
```

This is the result of the query above:

```
{service: {__typename: "Service", title: null, body: null}}
```